# How to inherit a constructor from a sub class

Tags: c#

I am writing an abstract base class. I want all the classes that inherit from it to inherit a constructor that basically does the same things for all the classes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Doing your constructor protected will do the stuff

```
public abstract class A
{
 protected A(string v) { V = v; }
 public string V { get; protected set; }
}

public class AA : A
{
 public AA(string v) : base (v) {}
}
```

Comment: I think OP tries to avoid to implement a constructor with the same signature. You can't inherit constructors in C#. only call those from the base (as you do in your code)

Comment: Personally, I think this is one of the biggest failures with C#. Every public method declared in a base class is automatically usable in derived classes, but all constructors need to be explicitly defined. I curse the C# team every time I have to write the same constructor which simply calls the base implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If the abstract base class has a default constructor (i.e. a constructor with no parameters), it will automatically be called by the derived classes constructors, unless they explicitly call another constructor of the base class.

```
abstract class B
{
    protected B()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected B(object foo)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class D : B
{
    public D() 
        : base() // not actually necessary, since it's called implicitly
    {
    }

    public D(object foo)
        : base(foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could complete the answer with the requirements for the derived class if the base class does not have a default constructor

Answer (score 0):

In your derived classes constructor, you will need to call your base constructor like so:

```
base(param1,param2,...)
```

If you do not call the base constructor explicitly, the default constructor in the base class will be called, if one exists. If not, you will get a compile error.